# JQuery: simple animate() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

Here's my function

```
$("#image-list-"+image_id+" .arrow").animate(
{
    opacity: 'toggle',
    left: "+=200px"
}, 5000);
```

It's an image tag. It will fade in correctly, but it's not moving to right.

I've tried

```
left: 200
left: "200px"
left: "+200"
left: "+=200"
left: "+200px"
left: "+=200px"
```

But the image refuses to move. What am I doing wrong? This is incredibly frustrating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `left` to have an effect, your element needs a `position: relative`, `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` styling as well.

A `position: static` (the default) will be unaffected by `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` styling.

Comment: @Jonathan - thanks :) time for bed here though, packing == exhausting

Comment: Didn't really consider that! Thanks, Nick!